# Codesandbox with ReactJS nog working in Internet Explorer Edge

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

When I try Codesandbox in the newest version of IE, it keeps showing 'Bundling dependencies'. I can't get most Codesandbox demo's to work in IE, they all have the same problem.

For example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp
https://voz37vlg5.codesandbox.io/

Is this a known problem? I can't find anything about it after googling it.
Does it work for anyone else in IE?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft stopped active development on IE in 2016. It is still maintained but new stuff doesn't find it's way to IE anymore. AFAIK codesandbox uses service workers which are not and will not be supported by IE. I could imagine this is why it doesn't work.

**EDIT**: Seems that service workers are only used for offline functionality. Any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: No warnings or errors at all. Just endless 'Bundling Dependencies...'